# Nvida Persistence Daemon fails to load Ubuntu GNOME 16.10

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, services, 16.10, persistence

The laptop I am using is a Lenovo Yoga 710 15' (with GTX 940MX). The computer can boot, however, I always get the nvidia persistence daemon load failure when I boot up.

And advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem here, GTX1060